# Visual studio 2015 preview new project error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Preview and I can`t start a new project(all types of projects).When I try to start it gives me an error: "Unable to instantiate custom import collection type." .Maybe someone have had this type of error and know solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same issue, if it helps to figure out the cause I reinstalled VS 2015 CTP5 because I was experiencing some other odd behaviour.

Comment: I reinstaled it and it helped me too

Comment: I got this AFTER I reinstalled (to go back to CTP4 from CTP5)

Comment: i reinstalled and same problem. is there any way to re install features from internet again as when repairing it install from local files rather than from internet ?